# Yesod live reload of Hamlet with GHCI instead of GHC?

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod, ghci, type-safety

I just heard about Yesod and started reading the book. In the Shakespeare chapter, about 3/4 down, they said...

"Reload mode is not available for Hamlet, only for Cassius, Lucius and Julius. There are too many sophisticated features in Hamlet that rely directly on the Haskell compiler and could not feasible be reimplemented at runtime."

Does this mean that the *server* has to get recompiled every time you change the HTML? Would it be any good to use Ghci to do the live compiling, or is that technology already being used at it's peak for Yesod?

This software seems like one of the more majestic projects. I really look forward to learning more about Yesod and this style of programming in general!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure (a) if you are asking about deploying the application after you change the Hamlet file or (b) if you just need real-time feedback without having to manually recompile during development.

Anyways if it is (a): I have not done it myself but I think the answer is yes, you will have to recompile and redeploy.

If it is (b): If you use  `yesod --dev devel` to launch your server, it will listen for any changes and automatically recompile. If you refresh the page, changes should be visible or if you have any errors, it will show up in the log.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It did, but my main question arose from the need to tear-down the server, recompile it all, then launch it again. Would it be possible to develop entirely within ghci? Rewrite your new function, kill the runnning function that behaves as the server, then swap out the new server (function)? I think this question more has to deal with the feasability of real-time application development in haskell itself, not specifically with yesod. I think it would be wonderful to have every program written in haskell to optionally be in development mode, the code compiled on-the-fly and not interrupt the app